# Linking error when building mupdf with MinGW-w64

Tags: linker, mingw, mupdf, jbig2

I tried to build mupdf libs with MinGW-w64. Compiling and ar operations were finished, but when linking the exec file, it reported errors like that

```
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_symbol_dict.o):jbig2_symbol_dict.c:(.text$_Exit+0x0): multiple definition of `_Exit'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$_Exit+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_symbol_dict.o):jbig2_symbol_dict.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): multiple definition of `llabs'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_symbol_dict.o):jbig2_symbol_dict.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): multiple definition of `atoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_symbol_dict.o):jbig2_symbol_dict.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `lltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_symbol_dict.o):jbig2_symbol_dict.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_symbol_dict.o):jbig2_symbol_dict.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): multiple definition of `wtoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_symbol_dict.o):jbig2_symbol_dict.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): multiple definition of `lltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_symbol_dict.o):jbig2_symbol_dict.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_text.o):jbig2_text.c:(.text$_Exit+0x0): multiple definition of `_Exit'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$_Exit+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_text.o):jbig2_text.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): multiple definition of `llabs'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_text.o):jbig2_text.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): multiple definition of `atoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_text.o):jbig2_text.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `lltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_text.o):jbig2_text.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_text.o):jbig2_text.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): multiple definition of `wtoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_text.o):jbig2_text.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): multiple definition of `lltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_text.o):jbig2_text.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_iaid.o):jbig2_arith_iaid.c:(.text$_Exit+0x0): multiple definition of `_Exit'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$_Exit+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_iaid.o):jbig2_arith_iaid.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): multiple definition of `llabs'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_iaid.o):jbig2_arith_iaid.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): multiple definition of `atoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_iaid.o):jbig2_arith_iaid.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `lltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_iaid.o):jbig2_arith_iaid.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_iaid.o):jbig2_arith_iaid.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): multiple definition of `wtoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_iaid.o):jbig2_arith_iaid.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): multiple definition of `lltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_iaid.o):jbig2_arith_iaid.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_int.o):jbig2_arith_int.c:(.text$_Exit+0x0): multiple definition of `_Exit'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$_Exit+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_int.o):jbig2_arith_int.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): multiple definition of `llabs'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_int.o):jbig2_arith_int.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): multiple definition of `atoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_int.o):jbig2_arith_int.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `lltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_int.o):jbig2_arith_int.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_int.o):jbig2_arith_int.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): multiple definition of `wtoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_int.o):jbig2_arith_int.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): multiple definition of `lltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_arith_int.o):jbig2_arith_int.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_generic.o):jbig2_generic.c:(.text$_Exit+0x0): multiple definition of `_Exit'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$_Exit+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_generic.o):jbig2_generic.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): multiple definition of `llabs'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_generic.o):jbig2_generic.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): multiple definition of `atoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_generic.o):jbig2_generic.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `lltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_generic.o):jbig2_generic.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_generic.o):jbig2_generic.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): multiple definition of `wtoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_generic.o):jbig2_generic.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): multiple definition of `lltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_generic.o):jbig2_generic.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_halftone.o):jbig2_halftone.c:(.text$_Exit+0x0): multiple definition of `_Exit'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$_Exit+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_halftone.o):jbig2_halftone.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): multiple definition of `llabs'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_halftone.o):jbig2_halftone.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): multiple definition of `atoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_halftone.o):jbig2_halftone.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `lltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_halftone.o):jbig2_halftone.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_halftone.o):jbig2_halftone.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): multiple definition of `wtoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_halftone.o):jbig2_halftone.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): multiple definition of `lltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_halftone.o):jbig2_halftone.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_mmr.o):jbig2_mmr.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): multiple definition of `llabs'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_mmr.o):jbig2_mmr.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): multiple definition of `atoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_mmr.o):jbig2_mmr.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `lltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_mmr.o):jbig2_mmr.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_mmr.o):jbig2_mmr.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): multiple definition of `wtoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_mmr.o):jbig2_mmr.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): multiple definition of `lltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_mmr.o):jbig2_mmr.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_refinement.o):jbig2_refinement.c:(.text$_Exit+0x0): multiple definition of `_Exit'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$_Exit+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_refinement.o):jbig2_refinement.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): multiple definition of `llabs'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$llabs+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_refinement.o):jbig2_refinement.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): multiple definition of `atoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$atoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_refinement.o):jbig2_refinement.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `lltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_refinement.o):jbig2_refinement.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltoa'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltoa+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_refinement.o):jbig2_refinement.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): multiple definition of `wtoll'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$wtoll+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_refinement.o):jbig2_refinement.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): multiple definition of `lltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$lltow+0x0): first defined here
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_refinement.o):jbig2_refinement.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): multiple definition of `ulltow'
build/mingw64-cross/release/libmupdf-third.a(jbig2_segment.o):jbig2_segment.c:(.text$ulltow+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:247: build/mingw64-cross/release/mutool] Error 1
```

Those errors were all about jbig2dec library. It seemes that those programs defined symbols like _Exit multiple times, but in source files, I didn't fond any use of such symbols. I used `nm` command to analyse the jbig2_segment.o file, then I found that

```
...
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 t .text$_Exit
0000000000000000 t .text$atoll
0000000000000000 t .text$jbig2_find_segment
0000000000000000 t .text$jbig2_free_segment
0000000000000000 t .text$jbig2_get_region_segment_info
0000000000000000 t .text$jbig2_parse_segment
0000000000000000 t .text$jbig2_parse_segment_header
0000000000000000 t .text$llabs
0000000000000000 t .text$lltoa
0000000000000000 t .text$lltow
0000000000000000 t .text$ulltoa
0000000000000000 t .text$ulltow
0000000000000000 t .text$wtoll
...
```

It show that symbols like _Exit and atoll were really defined, but there were no such symbols in the program source file. Except jbig2_xxx.o, other .o files had no such symbols.

Then, I used linux to build the same project, and it passed. So what caused this problem? how could I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried building jbig2dec standalone from source instead of the supplied third party?
When I build https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs9530/jbig2dec-0.19.tar.gz with MinGW-w64 it builds fine.
To build mupdf against it I had to add `LDFLAGS="-Wl,--as-needed -ljbig2dec"` to the make command.
Note that I did build all dependancies seperately so none are used from the mupdf supplied third party sources.

Comment: @BrechtSanders You were able to build jbig2dec-0.19 from [ArtifexSoftware] source? That's interesting, considering [MSYS2 had to patch `os_types.h`](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/commit/fd61ccaad1619ea296b3261d30487155a1737162), to build theirs.

Comment: @TamirEvan I build jbig2dec-0.19 from the source at: https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs9530/jbig2dec-0.19.tar.gz without any changes using `./configure LDFLAGS="-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition" && make`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround could be to use linker flag `-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition`, for example with `make LDFLAGS="-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition"`.

Personally I build MuPDF with MinGW-w64 without any of the suplied third party code. Instead I have all the dependancy libraries already compiled on my system and the build MuPDF with:

```
make NOX11=yes CC=gcc USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=yes SYS_FREETYPE_LIBS=-lfreetype CFLAGS="$(pkg-config --cflags libopenjp2) -I$(pwd)/include -I$(pwd)/fitz -I$(pwd)/pdf" SYS_GUMBO_LIBS="-lgumbo" LDFLAGS="-Wl,--as-needed -lfreetype -ljbig2dec -ljpeg -lopenjp2 -lz"
```

Comment: (1) `NOX11=yes` ??? When was the last time you built MuPDF? Testing for `NOX11` was replaced more than 7 years ago, in "Add MuJS submodule, implementation and build" ([commit db63530](https://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=commitdiff;h=db6353067cf545f4ca6fd854c8e8b4c4145dc537;hp=332fb2e7033f3376fcdcfe0762e15ce78d221fbc)). (2) As the OP seems to actually be trying to _cross-compile_ MuPDF to Mingw-w64, the second part of your answer would probably not be of much help to him. Also, unless he was using something like MSYS2, he'd have to package those third-party libraries with the app(s) too.

Comment: @TamirEvan

(1) Maybe the NOX11=yes was still in there from building older versions and I missed the fact that it's no longer needed.

(2) I build from MSYS2 shell, but use none of their brebuilt packages, instead I have built all the third-party packages myself from source. In fact, I'm working on a packaging system on my own to go with https://winlibs.com/

Comment: Sorry late. -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition flag works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue (multiple definitions of various symbols) using Artifex's stand-alone jbig2dec v0.19 library with MuPDF v1.21 and building with MinGW-w64.  What solved it for me was the comment Tamir Evan made about the patch that MSYS2 made to jbig2dec's os_types.h file.  This is my os_types.h which fixed the issue for me (the __CRT__NO_INLINE definition is critical).  No special linking flags (like -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition) needed.

```
/* os_types.h */
#ifndef _JBIG2_OS_TYPES_H
#define _JBIG2_OS_TYPES_H
#include <stdint.h>
#if (defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__MINGW64__))
#define __CRT__NO_INLINE 1
#endif
#endif /* _JBIG2_OS_TYPES_H */
```